# Wordpress - Hide future comments

Tags: wordpress, function

I have a specific case where I create comments with future dates on Wordpress posts, but, Wordpress displays future-dated comments.

For example, if I create a comment for 2050, it will be displayed on the frontend.

I would like a function that can be added to functions.php to only display comments on past dates.

The only reference I found about it on the internet was:

```
" AND wp_comments.comment_date < '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "'"
```

Could someone help me create this function?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is few months old now, but I faced the same problem and figured out the solution.
This will alter the query to get comments and display only these with date up to now.

```
add_filter('comments_clauses', function ($clauses) {
    $clauses['where'] .= " AND wp_comments.comment_date <= '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "'";
    return $clauses;
});
```